# how to setup two user_id columns in one model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have two models

```
class User 
   has_many :disputes
end

class Dispute
   belongs_to :user
end
```

So Dispute has `:user_id`, but my problem is that a Dispute has 2 sides  - the claimant and the indicted, both of which are users.

I tried to solve this problem by creating two columns: `:claimant_id` and `:indicted_id`, and passing arguments like `@dispute.claimant_id = current_user.id`, but after that I can't use a relationship tricks like `@dispute.user.name` or `@user.disputes` with my :`claimant_id` and `:indicted_id`.

Is there any way to set up two :user_id (like a claimant and an indicted) in one model and still maintain the relationships between Dispute and User models?

Comment: Is this your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731484/ruby-on-rails-double-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Double Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731484/ruby-on-rails-double-association)

For your case use  `class_name` as the second parameter to your `belongs_to` function and a hash with `foreign_key` and the id column name (as pointed out by @devkaoru), like so:

```
class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :claimant_id
  belongs_to :indicted, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :indicted_id
end
```

I think that should do it up right.

<sub>*Disclaimer: This is an untested solution*</sub>

Comment: If it's a duplicate, it's sufficient to flag it as such. The OP will e able to access the earlier question via boilerplate text that Stack Overflow adds after you flag a dupe.

Comment: Yes, it's sufficient. But I belive it's good to also answer the question more specifically in some cases (such as this, where there isn't a ton of helpful information and the OP is obviously new) as it helps out the OP a bit more.

Comment: Good solution. Thank to devkaoru and OneHoopyFrood) Have the last question. How to use relationships? Is it working for example @claimant.disputes or @dispute.indicted.name?

Comment: Try it and find out! Then let me know.

Comment: In rails console dispute.indicted.name work pretty fine, but reverse relationship indicted.disputes not work. I think I can use indicted_disputes = Dispute.select {|x| x.indicted_id == current_user.id}, but I don't have any idea how fast this works with huge database. Is the other way to use indicted-relationship and load some data like indicted.dispute.reason?

Comment: Yep, it has. I try to create some method in disputes_controller :
sent_disputes (where user.id == claimant_id) and received_disputes (where user.id == indicted_id). 
I try to change the question: how to setup user like claimant?
Usual way to setup user = User. find(params[:user_id]), I want build something similar: claimant = User.find(params[:claimant_id]) and after do claimant.disputes (where shall be only disputes where user is a claimant)

Comment: Unfortunately that is a non-trivial problem. It means you need to create the methods you were talking about earlier I think. There may be a way to do it more naturally but I'm not rails savvy enough to know how. You should ask another question that's more specific to that need.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't forget to upvote answers that helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You can go the route of having `:claimant_id` and `:indicted_id` on your `users` table, but in your class def you need

```
class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :claimant_id
  belongs_to :indicted, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :indicted_id
end
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to